# Dealing with image upload (keeping track) PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, image, codeigniter

In my site I will let users upload product images and each product image will have different versions of varying sizes. How do you suggest I keep track of all these images so I can easily deal with insertions and deletions?

The system that I have coded at the moment basically records image data (paths, sizes, date, etc) in a DB row on upload. Images file names are generated by

```
md5( microtime() ) . $this->auth->user_id;
// 55bedba35a57c710e73fee21106006b71
```

and paths like this:

```
'./img/'.substr($file_name,0,1).'/'.substr($file_name,1,1).'/'.substr($file_name,2,1);
// /img/5/5/b
```

so its

```
// /img/5/5/b/55bedba35a57c710e73fee21106006b71.jpg
```

That is for each "image" (the original image). I'm still not sure how to go about recording the versions.

The thing is I'm a bit paranoid about integrity so the thought of somehow images getting deleted but still having records or having images with no record bothers me.

Is there anything (library or something) that can help me connect the DB - Filesystem gap?

I'm working with CodeIgniter if that is of any help

Thanks in advance. Please let me know if I didn't make any sense, heh.

**EDIT**

I'm thinking of storing the original as a blob in the database then generating variations and placing them all in the same folder. This way I think it might be easier to regenerate all images in case of missing images and delete the folder to delete all files when necessary. This would probably make my DB size unbearable no? What do you think?

Comment: Depending on how big the images are, you could maybe store them directly in the database as a blob.. ? that way you only have one central point of storage. You db could get big fast though

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the amount and size of the images if you are planning to store them into the database. I have written eCommerce systems that serve thousands of images from a MySQL database of various sizes without issue except for load on the system.

The down side to storing the images in the database is that every image would require a PHP script to execute to serve it out, increasing the load on both the database server and the web server.

I would recommend that you use a hash to name the file, like md5, or sha1, and prepend the user_id to it, storing the hash into the database.

```
$filename = md5_file($filename) . $extension;
```

For versions I would have a table in the database that contained four columns + any extra metadata you wish to store.

Example:

```
image_id | parent_image_id | user_id | hash
-------------------------------------------------------
1        | NULL            | 1       | AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
2        | 1               | 1       | BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
3        | 2               | 1       | CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
```

Then you can have multiple sub-versions if you so desire, branching out from any version.

For the file system, for performance you should store the files in a bucket structure... if you use the hash method you could do the following...

Say the filename is "aabbccddeeff.jpg", you would store the file into folders like so:

images/aa/bb/cc/dd/eeff.jpg

This is especially important if you are going to have thousands of image files.